# Additional spaces in String having read text file to String using FileInputStream

Tags: spaces, text-files, fileinputstream

I'm trying to read in a text file to a String variable. The text file has multiple lines. 
Having printed the String to test the "read-in" code, there is an additional space between every character. As I am using the String to generate character bigrams, the spaces are making the sample text useless.
The code is

```
try {
  FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(textfile);   
  DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);     
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

  //Read corpus file line-by-line, concatenating each line to the String "corpus"
  while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    corpus = (corpus.concat(strLine));    
  }

  in.close();    //Close the input stream  
}
catch (Exception e) { //Catch exception if any
  System.err.println("Error test check: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

I'd be grateful for any advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your text file is likely to be UTF-16 (Unicode) encoded.  UTF-16 takes two or four bytes to represent each character.  For most western text files, the "in-between" bytes are non-printable and will look like spaces.

You can use the [second argument of InputStreamReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader(java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) to specify the encoding.

Alternatively, modify the text file (iconv on Unix, Save As.. dialog in Notepad on Windows):
[image]